# How to calculate the Kretschmann scalar in 3+1 decomposition?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, curvature

Does anyone know a source for calculating the Kretschmann scalar and/or 4D Riemann tensor using the variables of the 3+1 decomposition?

I need to monitor a curvature invariant and calculating it naively is proving to be extremely difficult. I feel like I'm missing out on a lot of simplifications.

Comment: Have you looked at lectures by E. Gourgoulhon [3+1 Formalism and Bases of Numerical Relativity](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0703035)?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't present a complete decomposition of the Riemann tensor, just the Ricci tensor. I can calculate it, I was just hoping that there was something to check my work against